# Expect array argument to have set length

Tags: jestjs

I'm a bit of a newbie to Jest so please forgive me if this is an obvious answer but I cannot find an answer after scrolling through the docs.

I have a function *(funcA)* which passes an array of different lengths to another function *(funcB)* dependent on the arguments that `funcA` receives. I'm attempting to test the the length of the array that is passed to `funcB` is correct based on the arguments that I give to `funcA`. I am not that bothered about the contents of the array, just that it has a certain length. This is my current attempt:

```js
// Modules
const funcA = require('./funcA')

// Mock
const funcB = jest.fn(pairs => {
    return pairs[0]
})

// Test
test('Should pass array of 3623 length', () => {
    const result = funcA(75)
    
    expect(result).toBeInstanceOf(Object)
    expect(funcB).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expect.any(Array).toHaveLength(3623))
})
```

I wanted to try to use [`any()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#expectanyconstructor) if I could but the following test results in the error:

> *TypeError: expect.any(...).toHaveLength is not a function*

I get the same error even if I wrap the `expect.any(...)` in another set of parentheses. Is there any way to achieve what I want?

Comment: How are funcA and funcB related? If funcA calls funcB, you cannot mock it by just assigning a spy to local funcB variable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A test that asserts only array length and ignores array contents is of little value. The more specific it is, the better. If specific array is expected, it can be specified as a fixture.

This assertion cannot work because `toHaveBeenCalledWith` is supposed to be expected result and cannot contain another assertion, `toHaveLength`.

In order to assert `toHaveBeenCalledWith` with an array with any elements, it should be:

```
expect(funcB).toBeCalledWith(Array(3623).fill(expect.anything()))
```

Another option is to assert the argument directly:

```
expect(funcB).toBeCalledWith(expect.any(Array))
expect(funcB.mock.calls[0][0]).toHaveLength(3623))
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for! I am also testing that the structure of all items within the array are object & have the correct properties