# Expect positive number parameter passed - jest

Tags: node.js, jestjs

The test is linked to this question here which I raised *(& was resolved)* a few days ago. My current test is:

```js
// Helpers
function getObjectStructure(runners) {
    const backStake = runners.back.stake || expect.any(Number).toBeGreaterThan(0)
    const layStake = runners.lay.stake || expect.any(Number).toBeGreaterThan(0)

    return {
        netProfits: {
            back: expect.any(Number).toBeGreaterThan(0),
            lay: expect.any(Number).toBeGreaterThan(0)
        },
        grossProfits: {
            back: (runners.back.price - 1) * backStake,
            lay: layStake
        },
        stakes: {
            back: backStake,
            lay: layStake
        }
    }
}

// Mock
const funcB = jest.fn(pairs => {
    return pairs[0]
})

// Test
test('Should call `funcB` with correct object structure', () => {
    const params = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(paramsPath, 'utf8'))
    const { arb } = params
    const result = funcA(75)
    
    expect(result).toBeInstanceOf(Object)
    expect(funcB).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
        Array(3910).fill(
            expect.objectContaining(
                getObjectStructure(arb.runners)
            )
        )
    )
})
```

The object structure of `arb.runners` is this:

```json
{
    "back": {
        "stake": 123,
        "price": 1.23
    },
    "lay": {
        "stake": 456,
        "price": 4.56
    }
}
```

There are many different tests around this function mainly dependent upon the argument that is passed into `funcA`. For this example, it's `75`. There's a different length of array that is passed to `funcB` dependent upon this parameter. However, it's now also dependent on whether the  `runners` *(`back` and/or `lay`)* have existing `stake` properties for them. I have a `beforeAll` in each test which manipulates the `arb` in the file where I hold the params. Hence, that's why the input for the runners is different every time. An outline of what I'm trying to achieve is:

1. Measure the array passed into `funcB` is of correct length
2. Measure the objects within the array are of the correct structure:

   2.1 If there are `stake`s with the runners, that's fine & the test is straight forward

   2.2 If not `stake`s are with the runners, I need to test that; `netProfits`, `grossProfits`, & `stakes` properties all have **positive** Numbers

*2.2* is the one I'm struggling with. If I try with my attempt below, the test fails with the following error:

> *TypeError: expect.any(...).toBeGreaterThan is not a function*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64198066/expect-array-argument-to-have-set-length), the problem is that `expect.any(Number).toBeGreaterThan(0)` is incorrect because `expect.any(...)` is not an assertion and doesn't have matcher methods. The result of `expect.any(...)` is just a special value that is recognized by Jest equality matchers. It cannot be used in an expression like `(runners.back.price - 1) * backStake`.

If the intention is to extend equality matcher with custom behaviour, this is the case for [custom matcher](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#custom-matchers-api). Since spy matchers use built-in equality matcher anyway, spy arguments need to be asserted explicitly with custom matcher.

Otherwise additional restrictions should be asserted manually. It should be:

```
function getObjectStructure() {
    return {
        netProfits: {
            back: expect.any(Number),
            lay: expect.any(Number)
        },
        grossProfits: {
            back: expect.any(Number),
            lay: expect.any(Number)
        },
        stakes: {
            back: expect.any(Number),
            lay: expect.any(Number)
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
expect(result).toBeInstanceOf(Object)
expect(funcB).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
expect(funcB).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
    Array(3910).fill(
        expect.objectContaining(
            getObjectStructure()
        )
    )
)

const funcBArg = funcB.mock.calls[0][0];

const nonPositiveNetProfitsBack = funcBArg
    .map(({ netProfits: { back } }, i) => [i, back])
    .filter(([, val] => !(val > 0))
    .map(([i, val] => `${netProfits:back:${i}:${val}`);
expect(nonPositiveNetProfitsBack).toEqual([]);

const nonPositiveNetProfitsLay = ...
```

Where `!(val > 0)` is necessary to detect `NaN`. Without custom matcher failed assertion won't result in meaningful message but an index and `nonPositiveNetProfitsBack` temporary variable name can give enough feedback to spot the problem. An array can be additionally remapped to contain meaningful values like a string and occupy less space in errors.